# How to enable plotting only if values are present in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts. I am recently stuck with plotting the highcharts.  I am using plotbands to plot the back color. If a value is present, it has to be shaded, if a value is not present, it should not be shaded.

For example, in this chart, for oranges, the shading is good because there are values for both positive and negative side. But for bananas, the shading is not correct.  It has only positive value, so only the positive side should be shaded, and not the negative side i.e., 0 to -2.5 should not be shaded with gray.

Any help is appreciated.

**Highchart column with plotbands:**

[image: Highchart column with plotbands]

Code below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {  
  chart: {  
    type: 'column'  
  },  
  title: {  
    text: 'Column chart with negative values'  
  },  
  xAxis: {  
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],  
    plotBands: [{   
      color: 'gray',  
      from: 0.5,  
      to: 1.5  
    },  
    {   
      color: 'gray',  
      from: 3.5,  
      to: 4.5  
    }],  
  },  
  credits: {  
    enabled: false  
  },  
  series: [{  
    name: 'John',  
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]  
  }, {  
    name: 'Jane',  
    data: [2, -2, -2, 2, 1]  
  }, {  
    name: 'Joe',  
    data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]  
  }]  
});
```

Comment: Can you add in your highcharts code?

Comment: Hi, Added code, and you can see here as well: https://jsfiddle.net/14a2yb6k/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use plotbands for what you have described, since they go from -∞ to ∞. However, you can use custom shapes and have them look like plotbands.

First off you will need to have a function fire when the chart is loaded:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.customRect = [] //We use this to keep track off all the shapes we create
      addPlotbands(this); //Function to find what area should be colored in what way
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need a function to detect when all values are positive,negative, or a mix. This can be done in the following way(note that this assumes all series have *exactly* the same number of points):

```
function addPlotbands(chart) {
  let series = chart.series
  let yMin = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
  let yMax = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

  for (let i = 0; i < series[0].data.length; i++) {
    let allAboveZero = true;
    let allBelowZero = true;
    for (let j = 0; j < chart.series.length; j++) {
      if (series[j].data[i].y >= 0) {
        allBelowZero = false;
      } else {
        allAboveZero = false;
      }
    }
    if (allAboveZero) {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, 0, yMax)
    } else if (allBelowZero) {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, yMin, 0)
    } else {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, yMin, yMax)
    }
  }
}
```

Then finally, you need a function to create a custom rectangle shape, which can be done like this:

```
function addCustomElement(chart, x, yMin, yMax) { //yMin and yMax refers to the window, not the data
  let yAxis = chart.yAxis[0]
  let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0]
  chart.customRect.push(chart.renderer.rect(
    xAxis.toPixels(x - 0.5, false),                                  //Leftmost pixel
    yAxis.toPixels(yMax, false),                                     //Top pixel
    xAxis.toPixels(x + 0.5, false) - xAxis.toPixels(x - 0.5, false), //Width
    yAxis.toPixels(yMin, false) - yAxis.toPixels(yMax, false)        //Height
  )
  .attr({
    'stroke-width': 2,
    fill: 'gray',
    zIndex: -1
  })
  .add());
}
```

This works well, however, when you resize the window, the shapes will not be resized. That can be solved by adding some extra code to the redraw event:

```
redraw: function() {
  if (this.customRect) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.customRect.length; i++) {
      this.customRect[i].destroy(); // Remove all the old rectangles before adding any new ones
    }
    this.customRect = [] //Empty the array of shapes
    let chart = this;
    setTimeout(function() { //We use a small timeout here to make sure the user is done resizing
      addPlotbands(chart)
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

```js
function addPlotbands(chart) {
  let series = chart.series
  let yMin = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
  let yMax = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

  for (let i = 0; i < series[0].data.length; i++) {
    let allAboveZero = true;
    let allBelowZero = true;
    for (let j = 0; j < chart.series.length; j++) {
      if (series[j].data[i].y >= 0) {
        allBelowZero = false;
      } else {
        allAboveZero = false;
      }
    }
    if (allAboveZero) {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, 0, yMax)
    } else if (allBelowZero) {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, yMin, 0)
    } else {
      addCustomElement(chart, i, yMin, yMax)
    }
  }
}

function addCustomElement(chart, x, yMin, yMax) {
  let yAxis = chart.yAxis[0]
  let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0]
  chart.customRect.push(chart.renderer.rect(
      xAxis.toPixels(x - 0.5, false), //Leftmost pixel
      yAxis.toPixels(yMax, false), //Topmost pixel
      xAxis.toPixels(x + 0.5, false) - xAxis.toPixels(x - 0.5, false), //Width
      yAxis.toPixels(yMin, false) - yAxis.toPixels(yMax, false) //Height
    )
    .attr({
      'stroke-width': 2,
      fill: 'gray',
      zIndex: -1
    })
    .add());
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.customRect = []
        addPlotbands(this);
      },
      redraw: function() {
        if (this.customRect) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.customRect.length; i++) {
            this.customRect[i].destroy();
          }
          this.customRect = []
          let chart = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
            addPlotbands(chart)
          }, 100);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Column chart with negative values'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],

  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, -3],
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, -2, -2, 2, 1, -1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5, -2]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/gbrjd2uk/

**API REFs: [Load event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load), [Redraw event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw), [Adding a rectangle](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect)**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use plotBands, you can create (by Highcharts SVGRenderer) white rectangles that cover the unwanted part of plotBands. Below you can find an responsive example of this solution:

```
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var chart = this,
                yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
                xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
                minPxY = yAxis.toPixels(yAxis.min),
                zeroPxY = yAxis.toPixels(0),
                series = chart.series,
                i,
                j,
                xValue,
                startCategory,
                endCategory,
                hasNegative;

            if (chart.correctedPlotBand) {
                Highcharts.each(chart.correctedPlotBand, function(el) {

                    el.destroy();
                });
                chart.correctedPlotBand = [];
            } else {
                chart.correctedPlotBand = [];
            }

            for (i = 0; i < series[0].points.length; i++) {
                hasNegative = false;

                for (j = 0; j < series.length; j++) {

                    if (series[j].points[i].y < 0) {
                        hasNegative = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!hasNegative) {
                    xValue = series[0].points[i].x;
                    startCategory = xAxis.toPixels(xValue - 0.5) - 1;
                    endCategory = Math.ceil(xAxis.toPixels(xValue + 0.5));

                    chart.correctedPlotBand.push(chart.renderer.rect(startCategory, zeroPxY, endCategory - startCategory, minPxY - zeroPxY)
                        .attr({
                            fill: '#fff',
                            zIndex: 0
                        })
                        .add())
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sm1kev4t/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect